# guardar diferentes valores en un mismo ngmodel dentro de un ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, bucles, ngfor

Buenos dias tengo un problema, tengo un ngfor y dentro del ngfor tengo un input que se repite de acuerdo a los valores del ngfor, todos los inputs generado utilizan el mismo ngmodel, y como saben al llenar un input la misma información se llena en los otros inputs, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que cada input se diferencia de los anteriores y como guardar esos valores en un arreglo.

aqui mi codigo:

```
COMPONENT.TS
//variable que voy a utilizar para guardar los valores de los inputs.

    String: nombre_cabeceras;

    //servicio que implemento en el ngfor.

        getcolumnas() {
            this.Restservice.get('/matriz/lastcolumna').subscribe(
              data => {
                if (data) {
                  this.columnas = data;
                  console.log(' exito obtencion columna', this.columnas)
                } else {
                  //this.showError();
                  console.log(' Error obtencion columna', this.columnas)
                }
                this.datos = true;
              });
          }
```

HTML.

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
        <h3 class="first">Item columna</h3>
        <div class="ui-g-8" *ngFor="let c of columnas">
          <input pInputText type="text" placeholder=" V{{c}}"  size="30"  [(ngModel)]="nombre_cabeceras">{{c}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

como ven al llenar un input el input de abajo de se llena con la misma informacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [$index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096653/angular-using-index-in-ng-model) en angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `component.ts` puedes definir `nombre_cabeceras` como un array y en la template puedes usar el índice para guardar los valores de los `ngModel`.

```
// comopnent.ts
nombre_cabeceras: string[] = [];
```

```html
// template 
<div class="ui-g-8" *ngFor="let c of columnas; let i = index">
    <input pInputText type="text" placeholder=" V{{c}}" size="30" 
 [(ngModel)]="nombre_cabeceras[i]">{{c}}
</div>
```

Comment: disculpa amigo, como podria imprimir los valores de los inputs?                   
       en el template                                                                                    nombrecabeceras: {{nombre_cabeceras[i}}                                                                               y en el ts con un console.log

Comment: en el template dentro del bloque del `ngFor` puedes poner `{{ nombre_cabeceras[i] }}`.  En el ts eso depende si es para temas de debug puedes crear un `<button (click)="showValues()">show vlaues</button>` y en el ts `showValues() { console.log(this.nombre_cabeceras); }`